# search for dropdown values is not working in datatable for text Active and Inactive

Tags: html, jsp, datatable

Here is my html code:

```
       <td>
           <option value="${i.status}">${i.status}</option>                                                                  
           <c:choose>                                                                                                            
           <c:when test='${i.status=="Active"}'>                                                                                     
           <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>                                                                            
           </c:when>                                                                                                                

           <c:otherwise>                                                                                                             
           <option value="Active">Active</option>                                                                                    
           </c:otherwise>                                                                                                      
           </c:choose>                                                                                                       
           </select>
       </td>
```

I have also tried for disabling smart search of datatable but then search is not working for other fields.

Comment: did you tried:   <c:when test='${i.status.equals("Active")}'>

Comment: No but I will try this one.

Comment: Yaa.I have tried but still it is not working

Comment: did you check the value of     i.status   ?

Comment: yes.my dropdown is working but search is not working on dropdown of datatable